# Unable to find the chromedriver executable

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, watir, selenium-chromedriver

> Unable to find the chromedriver executable. Please download the server from http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list and place it somewhere on your PATH. More info at http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)

On Ubuntu 13 with Watir and Ruby.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please download the server from http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list and place it somewhere on your PATH. More info at https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver.

**UPD:** Link that is not broken: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

Comment: "The page you asked for does not exist" https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/downloads/list

Answer (score 63):

For other people on MacOS:

```
brew cask install chromedriver
```

And you'll be good to go.

If using Homebrew 2.6.0 (released in 2020.12.01) or above, you should use:

```
brew install --cask chromedriver
```

Comment: for newer versions of brew you will just need "brew install chromedriver" instead of "brew cask install chromedriver"

Answer (score 10):

For Linux/Ubuntu users, only running the following command should be sufficient:

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-chromedriver
```

It takes care of addition the binary file to PATH as well.

Answer (score 3):

I am considering Ruby on Rails features tests. Steps to add chromedriver to selenium webdrivers initialization:

1) Download lastest chrome executable from https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

2) Declare webdriver path in rails spec helper as 
(For selenium 3.x)

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.driver_path = "/home/jazz/Desktop/web_drivers/chromedriver"
```

and this should be before driver initialization like `Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)`

For above 3.x, just pass driver path during initialization-

```
Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome,:driver_path => <path to chromedriver>)
```

All set. Load any feature spec in rails.It will open a chrome window.

Answer (score 2):

It also will work to add an environment variable named `webdriver.chrome.driver`.

set `webdriver.chrome.driver` to whatever the absolute path is.

Answer (score 2):

For me what have worked was to download the `chromedriver.exe` based on my Chrome version and place it on my directory "C:/ruby/...bin/"
I've tried to setup the environment variable but it didn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

I have another solution worth trying:

in `rails-helper.rb` go to this line and change `:firefox` to `:chrome`

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :firefox)
end
```

to

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
end
```

then, go to [ChromeDriver](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver) and run this:

```
brew tap homebrew/cask && brew cask install chromedriver
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Ruby and Watir. I have installed ChromeDriver according to this tutorial:

https://tecadmin.net/setup-selenium-chromedriver-on-ubuntu/

Then I had following error:

```
DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist while trying to initiate Chrome Browser
```

In my case error was solved by adding the arguments **--no-sandbox** and **--disable-dev-shm-usage** to browser contructor:

```
args = ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-dev-shm-usage']
browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, options: {args: args}
```

Finally, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The Chrome Drive Path changed again. The new Path which has Chrome Driver for all versions:

**Working Path**

1. https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
2. https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/

**Old Path -** https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

Include below on your **env.rb**

```
Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app,
    :browser => :chrome,
    :driver_path => "<PATH FOR UNZIPPED DRIVER FOLDER>"
  )
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows :

1. enter the link indicated in the error message
   https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.htm
2. download chrome driver
3. copy the chromedriver.exe file
4. go to the c:\windows folder
5. paste the chromedriver.exe

your code will now work.

Mac:

1. just enter cmd and type brew cask install chromedriver

your code will now work.

Linux:

1. just enter cmd and type sudo cp chromedriver /usr/local/bin

your code will now work.